# EACCES (Permission denied) in Travis CI Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci, android-permissions

I test my application locally using Espresso with an Android API 22 emulator and it works. I have this in my Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also ask for permissions at runtime, as required after Android 23. However, when Travis CI is running the tests with the same API emulator, the app throws an error:

```
02:10:29 V/InstrumentationResultParser: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/dd3c49bc-efdb-41b9-90af-e814ca17c59d.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: false

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-28.0.3
    - android-28
    - android-22
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22

before_script:
  - touch local.properties
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-22 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
 - ./gradlew clean build connectedCheck
```

This is the repo Travis is building:

[Android-CutOut](https://github.com/GabrielBB/Android-CutOut)

If you clone it, open with Android Studio and run the tests you can see it doesn't throw that error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use external storage on an Android Emulator image, you need to create external storage. Either you have a ready to go image that you can add with a path or you may supply the size of the sd card image using the -c parameter.

https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android

Comment: THIS IS IT !! Finally my builds are sucessful with my UI Tests (https://github.com/GabrielBB/Android-CutOut/runs/41269874) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Removing and adding the Android platform again fixed the error, but now the app crashes for the tiniest UI changes without any error. I have to restart the app every time to get it working again.

also one more thing,

**SD cards have a "write lock" slider on the side, 90 degrees from the contacts.**

**Make sure that your SD card is write enabled.**

Comment: Are you talking about a Travis CI environment? It does not sound like it. It works with no problems on my local machine emulators